# Input type text should not be editable

Tags: javascript, c#, html

**My Sample Code:**

```
`<input type="text" class="text" id="TxtName" runat="server" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" />`
```

i just need to input type `text` should not be edited after values set to this text box.

Comment: Just add `disabled` attribute in input text : `<input type="text" name="lname" disabled>`

Comment: The `disabled` attribute will prevent the value from being submitted with the form. The `readonly` attribute does not do that.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `readonly` to your `input` tag.

```html
<input type="text" class="text" id="TxtName" runat="server" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" readonly />
```

Alternatively, if you want to disable the user input field use `disabled`

```html
<input type="text" class="text" id="TxtName" runat="server" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" disabled  />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent user to change value of input field once input field has value than you can use **onblur** like

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="this.disabled=true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**readonly**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/readonly) attribute

```
<input type="text" value="" class="" readonly>
```